# How to do a point light on Windows Phone?

Tags: xna, shader, windows-phone, lighting

All of the stuff that I can find about point lights with XNA uses custom shaders, which aren't available on Windows Phone.  Can one of the 5 built-in effects be used to simulate a point light?  How do you do a point light on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

BasicEffect lets you specify Directional lighting, would it be possible for you to use one of these? just set it's location in world space and point it towards every model you render?